# Postgresql Schema and Data Compare

Tags: postgresql, red-gate-data-compare

Is it possible to compare postgresql database in Redgate SQL Compare tool.

or Any other recommend tool for postgresql database compare tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Redgate just has comparison tools for SQL Server and Oracle. You could try [PostgresCompare](https://www.postgrescompare.com/), which is an analogous tool to SQL Compare.

Comment: I used Red-Gate for SQL Server for years. When I switched to PostgreSQL, I settled on PostgresCompare and have been enjoying it for about a year, now.